use $this->authorizeResource in __construct() method in laravel controller
this my __construct() method :
public function __construct(){
    $this->authorizeResource(Event::class, 'event');
}

but i have this error:
Undefined method 'authorizeResource'.
I saw a tutorial that used this method, but it didn't work for me :(
I have no idea what to try

Make sure you have use \Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests; in your class.

Tutorials using different versions of Laravel are useless. Always check the version.
